# HTML5 Form: Page Is Reloading Instantly After Restyling (And It Shouldn't Be)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form. I have made it so that if your name is not put in, a red border is put on the name field. That works, BUT...it's for a split second, and then the page reloads. I want the red border to appear, and then stay there. For some reason it's for a split second. Can someone help me make it so the page doesn't reload after displaying the red border?

Here's the script.

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("Hogwarts").onsubmit = function () 
    {

        window.alert("Form submitted. Owl being sent...");
        var fname = document.getElementById("fName");

        if(!fName.value.match("^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+( [A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$"))
        {
            window.alert("You must enter your name.");
            addClass(fName, "errorDisp");
            document.getElementById("fName").focus();
        }
        else
            return true;
        }   
    }

    function addClass(element, classToAdd) 
        {
            var currentClassValue = element.className;

            if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
                if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
                    element.className = classToAdd;
                } else {
                    element.className += " " + classToAdd;
                }
            }
       }

      function removeClass(element, classToRemove) 
      {
        var currentClassValue = element.className;

        if (currentClassValue == classToRemove) {
            element.className = "";
            return;
        }

        var classValues = currentClassValue.split(" ");
        var filteredList = [];

        for (var i = 0 ; i < classValues.length; i++) {
            if (classToRemove != classValues[i]) {
                filteredList.push(classValues[i]);
            }
        }

        element.className = filteredList.join(" ");
      }
```

Here's the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <title>Hogwarts School of Witchcraft And Wizardry Application Form</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen"/>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <section>

            <header>
                <h1>Hogwarts School of Witchcraft And Wizardry</h1>
                <nav></nav>
            </header>

            <main>

                <form method="post" id="Hogwarts">
                <!--<form action="showform.php" method="post" id="Hogwarts">--!>

                    <fieldset id="aboutMe"> 
                        <legend id="aboutMeLeg">About Me</legend>

                        <div class="fieldleading">

                            <label for="fName" class="labelstyle">First name:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" autofocus maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="First Name" size="30">

                            <label for="lName" class="labelstyle">Last name:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" required maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="^[A-Za-z ]{3,}$" size="30">                        

                            <label for="age" class="labelstyle">Age:</label> 
                            <input type="number" id="age" name="age" required min="17" step="1" max="59" value="" placeholder="Age">

                        </div>

                            <div class="fieldleading">
                                <label for="date" class="labelstyle">Date Of Birth:</label>
                                <input type="date" name="date1" id="date" required autofocus value="">
                            </div>

                        <div id="whitegender">

                                <div class="fieldleading">
                                    <label class="labelstyle">Gender:</label>
                                </div>

                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" class="gender" required="required">Male<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" class="gender" required="required">Female<br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="other" class="gender" required="required">Other
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="contactInfo"> 

                        <legend id="contactInfoLeg">Contact Information</legend>

                        <div class="fieldleading">

                            <label for="street" class="labelstyle">Street Address:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="street" name="street" required autofocus maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="Street Address" pattern="^[0-9A-Za-z\. ]+{5,}$" size="35">

                            <label for="city" class="labelstyle">City:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required autofocus maxlength="30" value="" placeholder="City" pattern="^[A-Za-z ]{3,}$" size="35">

                            <label for="State" class="labelstyle">State:</label>
                            <select required id="State" name="State" >
                            <option value="Select Your State">Select Your State</option>
                            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="New York">New York</option>
                            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>

                        <div class="fieldleading">

                            <label for="zip" class="labelstyle">5-Digit Zip Code:</label>
                            <input id="zip" name="zip" required autofocus maxlength="5" value="" placeholder="Your Zip Code" pattern="^\d{5}$">

                            <label for="usrtel" class="labelstyle">10-Digit Telephone Number:</label>
                            <input type="tel" name="usrtel" id="usrtel" required autofocus value="" placeholder="123-456-7890" pattern="^\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$">

                        </div>  

                        <div class="fieldleading">

                            <label for="email1" class="labelstyle">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email1" id="email1" required autofocus value="" placeholder="hp1@zt.com" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" size="35">

                            <label for="homepage1" class="labelstyle">Home Page:</label>
                            <input type="url" name="homepage1" id="homepage1" required autofocus value="" placeholder="http://www.hp.com" pattern="https?://.+" size="35">

                        </div>

                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset id="yourInterests"> 
                            <legend id="yourInterestsLeg">Your Interests</legend>

                            <label for="Major" class="labelstyle">Major/Program Choice:</label>
                            <select required id="Major" name="Major" >
                            <option value="">Select Your Major</option>
                            <option value="Magic1">Magic Horticulture</option>
                            <option value="Magic2">Black Magic</option>
                            <option value="White">White Magic</option>
                            <option value="Blue">Blue Magic</option>
                            <option value="Non">Non-Wizardry Studies</option>
                            </select>

                        </fieldset>

                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitreset">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" value="Reset" class="submitreset">Reset</button>

                </form>

            </main>

            <footer>
                &copy; 2014 Bennett Nestok
            </footer>

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's the CSS.

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:black !important;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:red !important;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:green !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:blue !important;
    background-color:white !important;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ffffff; } /* gray80 */
:-moz-placeholder           { color: #ffffff; } /* Firefox 18- (one color)*/
::-moz-placeholder          { color: #ffffff; } /* Firefox 19+ (double colons) */
:-ms-input-placeholder      { color: #ffffff; }

body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: verdana;
    color:black;    
    background-image:url('bgtexture.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

footer {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:4px;
}

h1 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

button.submitreset {
    -moz-border-radius: 400px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 400px;
    border-radius: 400px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.labelstyle  {
    background-color:#a7a7a7;
    color:black;

    -moz-border-radius: 400px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 400px;

    border-radius: 400px;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

#aboutMe, #contactInfo, #yourInterests {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    text-align:left !important;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#Hogwarts {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:780px;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    padding-bottom: 20px !important;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#474747, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#474747, grey); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#474747, grey); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#474747, grey); /* Standard syntax */
    border-color:black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
    .labelstyle {
        display: none;
    }
    #Hogwarts {
        width:300px;
    }
    h1 {
        width:304px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
    .fieldleading {
    margin-bottom:0px !important;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-label { /* WebKit browsers */
        color: transparent;
    }
    :-moz-label { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
        color: transparent;
    }
    ::-moz-label { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
        color: transparent;
    }
    :-ms-input-label { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
        color: transparent;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
        color: grey !important;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
        color: grey !important;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
        color: grey !important;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
        color: grey !important;
    }
    #aboutMe, #contactInfo, #yourInterests {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:left !important;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
}

br {
   display: block;
   line-height: 10px;
}

.fieldleading {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

legend {
    color:white;
}

#whitegender {
    color:white;
}

#moreleading {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

/*opera only hack attempt*/
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
    .fieldleading {  
    margin-bottom:30px !important;
    } 
}  

.errorDisp {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to stop form submit:

```
document.getElementById("Hogwarts").onsubmit = function () 
{
    window.alert("Form submitted. Owl being sent...");
    var fname = document.getElementById("fName");

    if(!fName.value.match("^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+( [A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$"))
    {
        window.alert("You must enter your name.");
        addClass(fName, "errorDisp");
        document.getElementById("fName").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    }   
}
```

-Or-

```
document.getElementById("Hogwarts").onsubmit = function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert("Form submitted. Owl being sent...");
    var fname = document.getElementById("fName");

    if(!fName.value.match("^[A-Z][A-Za-z]+( [A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$"))
    {
        window.alert("You must enter your name.");
        addClass(fName, "errorDisp");
        document.getElementById("fName").focus();
    }
    else
        return true;
    }   
}
```